# Js display element after certain amount of time WITH transition

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want an HTML element to show after a certain amount of time, and I achieved this with JQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $(".element").delay(4000).fadeIn();
});
```

and modifying the CSS `display: none`

My question is how can I show the element with a bit of transition? I tried to put this on the style of the element:

```
transition: all 4s;
```

But it won't work. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As transitions don't work on CSS display you need to use something else.

One thing you can transition is opacity (as it's measurable). So try

```
opacity: 0;
```

for where you want it to be equivalent to `display: none;` and

```
`opacity: 1;`
```

equivalent to `display: block;`

Answer (score 0):

`display: none` won't work for the transition.
Use `visibility: hidden`

```
.element {
  transition: all 4s;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but this seems not to be working well with JQuery as the `$(".element").delay(1000).fadeIn();` isn't displaying anything and the element remains hidden

Comment: Actually just solved the problem, you are right `display: none` doesn't work with the transition, I then replaced the Jquery code with another one and solved it, thanks!